# Why Basel problem shows all time the same number?

Tags: c

Could you tell me why this did not work?
I have to show Pi number from Basel problem, but I don't know why the program shows the same number all the time, despite the fact I choose different 'numbers'.
Thanks a lot!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define Pi 3.14159
int main()
{
    int number;
    printf("max number: ");
    scanf("%d",&number);
    float euler;
    float sum=0;
    for(int i=1; i<number;i++)
    {
        sum=sum + (1/(i*i));
    }
    euler=sqrt(6*sum);
    printf("Euler: %lf \n",euler);
    printf("Pi from math library = %f",Pi);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `[I] choose different 'numbers'` give us an idea about the range - what results *do* you get for 1, 2, 7, 42?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the expression `(1/(i*i))` is calculated using integer mathematics. In other words, the result is always an integer, and for any value of `i` greater than 1, the result will always be 0.

The simplest fix is to rewrite that expression as `(1.0f/(i*i))`. This will square `i`, convert the result to a `float`, and then do the division.

Comment: @KamilaNowak you should *accept* Tim's answer, since it solved your problem!

Answer (score 0):

the posted code is mixing `integer` division with `double` literal and is expecting the result to be a `float`

The following proposed code :

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the implemented functionality

and now, the proposed code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
// define a float value rather than a double value
#define Pi 3.14159f

int main( void )
{
    int number;
    printf("max number: ");
    scanf("%d",&number);

    float euler;
    float sum=0;

    for(int i=1; i<number;i++)
    {
        // perform float math rather than integer math
        sum=sum + (1.0f/(float)(i*i));
    }

    euler=sqrtf(6*sum);  // < note float version rather than double version
    printf("Euler: %lf \n",euler);
    printf("Pi from math library = %f",Pi);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: double literal?

Comment: @TimRandall,  remember that invoking a macro results in a text replacement operation, so invoking `Pi` results in the text `3.14159f`  and if the `f` were not there, it would be a `double` literal